# How to include duplicate samples (same locations, different temporal sampling) in Geographically Weighted Logistic Regression?

Tags: r, time, geographically-weighted-regression

I want to assess local most important predictors for a specific event within a region. The same locations (grid) were all sampled in two different time occasions.
I am assuming predictors to be spatially varying, but temporally stationary.
The problem is that distance matrix calculation fails to run due to duplicate locations.
Is there a way to carry this "atemporal" GWLR, or a workaround, interpreting the two different regression analyses as a global model?

I am running GWmodel, in R.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example using, perhaps, sample data? It is very useful for us to be able to replicate your error message.